# iphone app with add to calendar

Tags: iphone, events, calendar

i'm creating an iphone application which can add events into local iphone calendar.

i have implemented a process here the source

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

the problem with this is it doesnt show the iphone new event add screen. which can change the time of the event  . is thr any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is correct since you create the the `MKEvent` programmatically.

If you lookup [`EventKitUI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=EventKitUI) this has clases that will allow you to present the user with default Event creation view controllers. Like the [`EKEventViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009572)